# JavaScript functions of remote sites are not invoking on UIWebview in IOS development

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am developing a Web Browser in Xcode (iOS) for iPhone and iPad. Everything is going fine but when I tried to open a PopUp window (opened by JS function) or clicking on Picker for populating values nothing happened. Help me out how to enable popups and Javascript in UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

User UIWebView delegate methods or right delegate yourself to handle this. I have used java script in my code in default web browser of iPhone and used

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Comment: I am bit new in Xcode. Can you please elaborate your answer to make it more understandable.  Thanks

Comment: Please tell how to enable popups and javascript in UIWebView IOS.